# How to change file permissions when you don't have permission to change file permissions?

Tags: windows-7, permissions

I often (like just this morning) have a situation where I need to delete or replace a file that may be located in folders like C:\Windows. When I try to do this I always get access denied. Every resource I can find shows me step by step how to modify the permissions, I already know how to do this. The problem is when I try to modify permissions and it tells me access denied. I don't have permission to modify the permissions! This happens even when I launch Windows Explorer or CMD as Administrator (my account is Admin), and even when I tried using cacls. UAC is at the lowest possible setting so it never bugs me. What's the deal Windows 7? Why can't I own all my files? It's so annoying that sometimes I actually boot Linux to go edit/modify a Windows file! Ok rant over, but can anyone solve this for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried taking ownership over the file. Instructions for hand right click menu [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1911-take-ownership-shortcut.html).

Comment: tried this to no avail, the take ownership option appears in most folders: http://i.imgur.com/qOkC9.png however not in the Windows folder: http://i.imgur.com/Y8pd4.png

Comment: HOWEVER, I was able to see the Take Ownership option while clicking on the Windows folder itself, I hope it's OK that I now own the whole Windows folder! Now I can edit the files I wanted, THANKS!

Comment: and one more time, I wish I could see what Take Ownership was doing so I knew how to do it manually, any ideas on how to view this?